# Error when trying to plot a map in folium

Tags: python, folium

I'm getting an error which is really weird to me because I have done the exact same thing before and no error popped up. Here I'm trying to plot some points in a map of Jacksonville FL.

This is my code:

```
map_jsv = folium.Map(location = [latitud, longit], zoom_start = 10 )
for lat, lng, neighborhood in zip(df['Latitude'], df['Longitude'], df['Neighborhood']):
    label = neighborhood
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html = True)
    folium.CircleMarker([lat,lng],
                        radius = 5,
                        popup = label,
                        color = 'red',
                        fill = True,
                        fill_color = '#3186cc',
                        fill_opacity = 0.7,
                        parse_html = False).add_to(map_jsv)
map_jsv
```

Of course I imported folium and also matplotlib.cm and .colors
but I get this error:

> `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

I have no clue, thanks beforehand...

Comment: Are you overwriting 'label' with 'label'? `label=neighborhood;label=folium.Popup(label, parse_html = True);`

Comment: @r-beginners no actually, it works well, because they are defining diferent things, the first label is for defining what to show when you click in every point, and the second label is to define how every point will look like

Answer (score 0):

Hey folk I just solved it, the problem wasn't with Folium, it was with the df, it changed his type when I dropped the null values with df.dropna, fixed it with a parenthesis: **df.dropna()** LOL.  Have a great day

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).